# Sort by descending in a subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query that counts all `Votes` across all `PollOptions` that belong to all existing `Polls`. This works fine, but now I want to implement pagination, which returns latest `Polls` first. I tried to do it like this:

```
SELECT offset_polls.id AS pollId, offset_polls.title, poll_options.id AS pollOptionId, text, vote_count 
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM polls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
) as offset_polls 
JOIN poll_options ON poll_options.poll_id = offset_polls.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT poll_option_id, COUNT(poll_option_id) as vote_count 
    FROM votes 
    GROUP BY poll_option_id 
) as votesCount ON  poll_options.id = votesCount.poll_option_id
ORDER BY offset_polls.id desc
```

The problem is that the first subquery ignores ORDER BY - yes I know it's SQL standard to do that. The way I did it, no rows are returned. If I don't use `ORDER BY` in the first subquery, the entire query works as 'intented', but `Polls` are, of course, returned from oldest to newest. How can I solve this in SQL? I could get all rows and do pagination on them afterwards, but I'm pretty sure that would be inefficient - (working in Node.js).

**EDIT**

The above query works as intended. The 'bug' was in my database seeding files.

Comment: Can you provide sample data + current vs. expected results?

Comment: @sstan This would be sample data: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0VWLeXNg) . As I've said, when I run the above query, I get 0 rows. I want it to return something like this: [wanted](http://pastebin.com/rvuFhLFF), except that it only returns 10 (`LIMIT 10`) most recent (`ORDER BY id DESC`) polls with their options and aggregated votes. But I don't know how to d that except by filtering 10 most recent polls in my first subquery using `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your sample data and I don't see any issue with the behavior of postgresql. What happens is that when you run the query

```
SELECT * FROM polls ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

it returns all polls with the following `id`s: `20`,`19`,`18`,...,`11`. Then, you join those rows with `poll_options` and you get nothing because there are no rows with a `poll_id` in that range:

```
# SELECT * FROM poll_options WHERE poll_id BETWEEN 11 AND 20;
 id | text | poll_id 
----+------+---------
(0 rows)
```

If you remove the `ORDER BY` clause from the `offset_polls` subquery, then it will include 10 "random" rows for which there might be some poll options, which is why the query returns some rows. So `ORDER BY` in this case in not ignored and behaves exactly as you would expect that it would.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It turns out that when I was seeding `poll_options`, I only added them to the first 10 polls (1 - 10), so when trying to get polls (11-20) they would return no rows when `JOIN`ing with `poll_options`. The query itself works as intended.